# Android studio failed to resolve com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating Android Studio and project gradle to support android 33.
When I build the project it is unable to resolve these dependencies

```
implementation 'com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11'
implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
implementation 'com.camerakit:jpegkit:0.1.0'.`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2OaG.png)

I tried multiple version of the dependencies but no success.

Answer (score 3):

You are not alone. I have the same issue. Here is a link how to fix it: https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android/issues/643#issuecomment-1719550133

I will copy/paste here the solution(it's not mine):

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.CameraKit:camerakit-android:v1.0.0-beta3.11'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.41'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
```

Then download the Source code for jpegkit-v0.1.0

https://github.com/CameraKit/jpegkit-android/archive/refs/tags/v0.1.0.zip

Extract, copy/paste folder jpegkit in the root folder of your project.

In build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':jpegkit')
```

in settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':jpegkit'
```

Credits to: **fwallz** from Github

**PS: I found another solution - just use other repository:**

```
implementation 'com.github.CameraKit:camerakit-android:v1.0.0-beta3.11'
implementation 'com.github.CameraKit:jpegkit-android:v0.2.2'
```

More info here: https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android/issues/643#issuecomment-1669025090

Comment: Thanks @nasko700, don't you have any idea why the older one doesn't work anymore:
`Could not find com.wonderkiln:camerakit-android:0.13.4`